# Python socket connections have one second delay every 9 connections on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, linux, sockets, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a data acquisition system on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It is deployed at a remote site, so my ability to change the physical configuration is limited. We do have someone on site who has been able to perform simple tests with the configuration.

We're running a python script to do data acquisition. However, we noticed that at high data rates, we were experiencing odd backups in our data buffer. After several hours of debugging, we were able to narrow the issue down to the following test case:

```
for i in xrange(500):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(('1.2.3.4', 5678))
    sock.close()
```

When the above code executes most samples execute almost instantaneously, but every 9th sample takes exactly one second to execute. Oddly, when actually taking data, the period is much shorter - 650ms or so in one test - and more connections succeed before the glitch sample (in that case, the glitch sample only takes ~400ms of that 650ms interval). Below is a plot of connection latency vs time for both instances. Axes are in seconds.)

[Latency between connections. connect-and-close in blue, system under load in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StzBH.png)

Here is a subset of the debugging we attempted, and whether the problem persisted or not in each case. Apologies for the brevity; if any step is unclear, I'm happy to provide follow-up information.

- Data acquisition with netcat: Works
- Run python script between two Ubuntu 14.04 machines (against nc listener, not able to test with data source): Works
- Connect to another computer running a netcat listener, instead of data source, from acquisition computer: Problem persists
- Call `shutdown()` before `close()`: Problem persists
- Tried using `asyncore` to run server: Problem persists
- Tried opening the sockets in threads: Problem persists
- Toggled various `net.ipv4.tcp_*` kernel parameters: Problem persists

From the above, the only consistency I've been able to discern is that python running on this particular machine encounters this issue. I have not yet had a chance to test this on another Ubuntu 16.04 (or any other 4.x kernel, for that matter), so I don't know if it's related to a change in the networking stack or not. I will continue to run various test to try to diagnose this issue, but any ideas are appreciated!

**Update:**

The result of `ulimit -a` (nothing jumps out at me as unusual).

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 40
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 32053
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 32053
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I will run the TIME_WAIT test soon and post the results. Another test I'm hoping to run is running both the netcat and python calls with strace to see if/how the arguments to socket and connect differ.

Comment: Please check `ulimit`. I suspect there must be some limiting factor to number of connections you can have assuming that the remote server has the capacity to handle all incoming connections at that rate. Also, use netcat to monitor TIME_WAIT sockets, might be that connections are not closed properly. If that is the case, try : `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`. Please let me know about the progress :)

Comment: What is the listen queue value? On the server side? When it fills up, syn sent by client will be dropped and tcp retransmission happens.this default is 3 sec(may be your systems are tuned to be 1 sec),to confirm, you should capture tcpdump and verify

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the helpful suggestions. In retrospect, tcpdump is the first thing I should have checked, so thank you Venkat for substituting in for my own judgement.

This appears to be a bug with the vendor software. Tcpdump showed that when running the python test, the device would preempt the handshake and send re-send a response to the last data query issued. Indeed, the SYN was re-transmitted 1 second after the packet was dropped, and the cycle continued.

The 9 packets seems to be a coincidence of the latency (which was suggested by the drift in the posted plot) - the response is triggered immediately, and just happened to preempt the 9th packet; a single request with netcat (e.g. `printf "" | nc 1.2.3.4 5678`) would trigger the data re-transmission.

We will try to work with the vendor to get this issue resolved. In the meantime, we may try to use settimeout and handle the timeout exception by re-establishing the connection.

Thank you again!